# Differentiable not $C^1$ and Darboux property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Are there any differentiable not $C^1$ function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f'(0)<f'(1)$ such that there exists $c \in (f'(0),f'(1))$ that $f'$ doesn't reach value $c$?

[Classical example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58329/looking-for-a-function-f-that-is-n-differentiable-but-fn-is-not-cont) of differentiable but not $C^1$ function doesn't work here.

Comment: I do not understand: any differentiable function has the Darboux property. Can you explain better your question?

Comment: He's talking about the Darboux property on $f'(x)$, he explained it correctly

Comment: No, every derivative has the intermediate value property/Darboux property.

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every derivative has the intermediate value property/Darboux property. That follows from the mean value theorem (and the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions):

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $g\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. Let $a < b$ such that $[a,b] \subset I$. If $g'(a) = g'(b)$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we may assume that $g'(a) < g'(b)$ [replace $g$ with $-g$ if necessary]. Choose $c \in (g'(a),g'(b))$. Consider the quotient

$$m = \frac{g(b) - g(a)}{b-a}.$$

If $m = c$, the mean value theorem asserts the existence of a $t\in (a,b)$ with $g'(t) = c$. If $m < c$, then define

$$h(x) = \begin{cases}\quad g'(b) &, x = b \\ \dfrac{g(b) - g(x)}{b-x} &, a \leqslant x < b,\end{cases}$$

and if $m > c$, define

$$h(x) = \begin{cases}\quad g'(a) &, x = a\\ \dfrac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a} &, a < x \leqslant b.\end{cases}$$

Then $h$ is continuous with $h(a) < c < h(b)$, and the intermediate value theorem asserts the existence of an $s \in (a,b)$ with $h(s) = c$. Then the mean value theorem asserts the existence of a $t \in (a,s)$ resp. $t \in (s,b)$ with $g'(t) = c$.