# Everywhere continuous and differentiable $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ that is not smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, real-numbers

I can't seem to find any counterexamples to the statement "all functions that are continuous and differentiable at every point of the reals are smooth," nor can I find anyone asserting or proving this statement.  Are there known functions that are continuous and differentiable at every point (with no holes / discontinuities / bounded domain) but are not smooth, that is, after some number of derivatives the derivative function is no longer fully differentiable?

Comment: Forgot to specify that I am talking about real functions only, if that wasn't clear - complex functions that are discontinuous off the real axis are not interesting counterexamples!

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth" --- continuous derivative or infinitely differentiable (or something else)? FYI, both uses of "smooth" occur quite often here, and nearly always without the questioner saying what "smooth" means until asked.

Comment: Dave: infinitely differentiable was the one I was using, since that's the limit of "smoothness" and thus what I thought was the unequivocal meaning of "smooth" (I specified this in the question at the end - it is "not smooth" if it is no longer totally differentiable after some derivative)

Comment: Actually, when I saw the part about totally differentiable, I thought you were talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), although I did wonder why you used the term in a non-multivariable setting (but not enough to think carefully about what you might have intended, since your question already had several answers). Incidentally, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58370/13130) might be of interest.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was using the word "totally" as a non-technical synonym for "completely."  My bad - it's been years since I took multivariable calc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Take, for instance$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\-x^2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't thinking about just composing a piecewise function like this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

An example is

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{for } x<0\\x^2 & \text{for } x\geq 0 \end{cases}.$$

It is clear that the function is continuous and differentiable for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. But $f'(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich I think you didn't notice the prime. I said that $f(x)$ differentiable. And $f'(x)$ (the derivative of f(x)$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich No contradiction.. $f$ differentiable always, but $f'$ (not $f$) isn't always.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be the continuous, nowhere differentiable Weierstrass function. Then $f(x)=\int_0^x W(t)\,dt$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R,$ but $f''(x)$ fails to exist for every $x.$

Comment: This is an interesting answer, probably the most extreme one easily available. Thanks!