# Differentiability class: Example of maps that are $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$.

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Is there a classical example for the fact that the differentiability class satify
$$
C^{k+1} \subsetneq C^{k}
$$
I'm interested in the $C^{k+1} \neq C^{k}$, then is I'm looking for a **classical**

> Example of maps that are $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$. Maps $f_j:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

For a compact interval the following example should work
$$
f_k:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{for $x\in[0,1)$}\\
1&\text{for $x\in[1,2]$}
\end{cases}
$$
then I build recursively $f_{k-1}$ by integrating $f_k$ thus the obtained $f_0$ or $f_1$ is $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$.

Comment: See my answer to [Looking for a function $f$ that is $n$-differentiable, but $f^{(n)}$ is not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58329).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Very interesting and elaborate answer! We (the search engine and I) missed it in the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) classical enough?  It is ***continuous but nowhere differentiable***; if we integrate it $k$ times we obtain a function which is $C^k$ but not $C^{k + 1}$ for any point in its domain!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is even not continuous. Set $F_1(x)=\int_0^x |t|dt$ and $F_{k}(x)=\int_0^x F_{k-1}(t)dt.$

Comment: Although if you shift the indices it doesn't really matter as long as you start with something integrable.

Comment: No, $\int_0^x tdt$ is $\mathcal C^\infty $. And yes, the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ElliotG: I don't understand your comment. My example is a correct one.

Comment: It's nothing. Just that you could start with a step function first if you wanted. The second iteration of the integral will be $C^1$, etc.

Comment: Elliot's comment is about mine example, I suppose.

Comment: @ElliotG: Indeed, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a *classical* example... Still, let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \; f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{k+2} \displaystyle \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\[2mm] 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

Then, $f \in \mathcal{C}^{k}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ but $f \notin \mathcal{C}^{k+1}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$.

Answer (score 0):

What about $f_k(x)=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}|x|\cdot x^k$?  We have that $f^{(k)}_k(x)=|x|$.